# How to change New label badge in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to change New label/badge in WordPress WooCommerce? I cant find location of code logic which creates this label.

Comment: This doesn't come from default Woocommerce. It's related to your theme, or a plugin. So nobody can guess for you where this could be… and that's why you *"looked a lot of instructions from internet, but you didn't find anything"*

Comment: "...this doesn't come from default Woocommerce..." is answer to my question. I just need that explanation. Thanks a lot for this @LoicTheAztec :)